Sorting filtered data by custom order with formula (Excel)
My first sheet contains information about a whole lot of pets entered into a big show. Every unique pet has it's own row, and the columns show values like handler, age, color and gender. I also have columns for specific competitions during the show, where you can find if and at which level it's competing at in that specific competition (the ones entered in that competition have their level specified in the cell, like "Novice", and the ones not entered have empty cells). I get this data when they enter (by form, so I just copy and paste the whole row). No problems there.
Sheet 2:
This is where I want the starting orders in the different competitions, so that I can easily just print them out.
I have a formula to extract the data from the rows containing text in a specific competition column. I get the name, handler and competition level displayed perfectly. But I also want them automatically sorted by the level.
And here's my problem: The levels aren't in alphabetical order.
Since the total show has about 40 different competitions, I of course want this to be made just from Sheet1, not having to sort 40 lists manually in Sheet2.
For example:
The pets competing at Novice should be on top of the list, while the pets competing at First Level should be below them and then Second Level and so on, so reverse alphabetical order isn't an option either. And the list must say which level they are on so I can't change it into numbers.
This is the formula that gives me the information I want into the cells in sheet2, but of course not in the right order:
=CHOOSECOL((FILTER((Sheet1!$A$4:$AP$100);(Sheet1!N$4:N$100<> "");"None"));1;2;9;14)
Column N (no 14) is the one saying which level is used for this specific competition.
I'm on Microsoft Excel for Mac, Version 16.88.
[The look of my participant list in Sheet1, I know it's zoomed out but maybe it can give an idea about how it looks][1]
[A list I want to extract from Sheet1 and automatically sort in Sheet2 (no real names here, just made a small sample][2]
I have tried so many things I've found when googling, and nothing has worked so far (and to be honest I don't know if I wrote the formulas correct). I would really appreciate some help, I have barely used Excel before.
Edit:
I ended up cheating for a bit. Using the suggested IFS helper column as my fifth shown column, sorted by that one and changed it into white text color. It was good enough for what I needed (printed lists) while still being able to copy+paste the info from the forms filled in by the competitors :)

A data sample would be nice to work with, if possible, [edit] in, using Table Markdown generator.

Edit: To make it work, using Excel 365, inspired by P.b.
Add helper column, say in column BI of Sheet 1: =IFS($N$5:$N$100="Novice";1;$N$5:$N$100="First Level";2;$N$5:$N$100="Entry";3;$N$5:$N$100<>"Entry";"")
In sheet2, use the following formula: =LET(_Data;FILTER((Sheet1!$A$4:$BI$100);(Sheet1!N$4:N$100<> "");"None"); _SortData;SORTBY(_Data;CHOOSECOL(_Data;61)); _Result;CHOOSECOL(_SortData;1;2;9;14); _Result)
Sheet1

Sheet2


Edit, Original answer below, this way doesn't work.

If you have room for a spare column, you can do as follow:
Make your spare column, and use a formula like IFS(N:N="Novice";1;N:N="First Level";2,--insert levels--;--and numbers--;N:N<>"name of last level";"") (fill in after with as many levels as you have).
Then you can use SORTBY like so:=SORTBY(array you want to sort;helper column)
So your final formula will look like: =SORTBY(CHOOSECOL((FILTER((Sheet1!$A$4:$AP$100);(Sheet1!N$4:N$100<> "");"None"));1;2;9;14);Sheet1!$Y$4:$Y$100)
Where Sheet1!$Y$4:$Y$100 is where you created your helper column.


Since the result already contains the level, we don't need a helper, we can sort on the 4th column of the filter result.

@P.b but OP stated the levels aren't in alphabetical order, hence why I added a helper column.

SORT sorts in numerical/alphabetical order

Otherwise I'd list the level names in order in let say I1:I3 and use something like =let(res,[original formula],sortby(res,xmatch(take(res,,-1),I1:I3)))

I tried it, but only get ##### as a result with the final formula: =SORTBY(CHOOSECOL((FILTER((Sheet1!$A$4:$BI$100);(Sheet1!N$4:N$100<> "");"None"));1;2;9;14);Sheet1!$BI$4:$BI$100)
I tried to add ;1 at the end as well as Excel suggested it, but it didn't make any difference. (the IFS in column BI seems to work fine)

@imperativ he used Sheet1 for both the helper and the data. Remove Sheet1 from the sort argument of SORTBY and it should work.

@P.b I have the helper column in Sheet 1 as well, do I need to move it for this to work?

His solution uses your formula as a helper, the column behind it as a second helper and finally he sorts the formula spill by the ifs spill. Have you tried my suggestion using sort (without helpers)? Using the IFS on the whole set will error for values not mentioned in the IFS.

@imperativ I did something wrong with the first solution (apparantly you can't instant do SORTBY on FILTER/CHOOSECOL; I've added in another way, this seems to work for me.

@Excellor It works! Thank you so much! I really appreciate all the help

Just wrap your formula in SORT using the 4th column as sort index:
=SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(Sheet1!$A$4:$AP$100;1;2;9;14);Sheet1!N$4:N$100<>"");4)
(I kept the ; delimiter in the answer, like in the version from your question)

Here's one way (tested under Microsoft 365 on Mac):
Using LC:1 as example

List classes in the grouping order: klasserna, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT("LD,LC,LB,LA,MsvB,MsvA,SvårB,SvårA", ","))

Split level by :,

Lookup LC 's index, assign 100 (more than the number of classes) if not found, convert to number.
TEXT(IFERROR(XMATCH(INDEX(split, , 1), klasserna), 100), "000")
Convert the group number1 (-- is used to get text number as number) to text and join; this will be used for sorting
& "-" & TEXT(--INDEX(split, , 2), "000")


Filter, it is very similar to yours (<> ""), using TRIM here and in other places help to get expected results:
LEN(TRIM(CHOOSECOLS(data, col_num_competion))) > 0

Selecting completion name for report with drop-down list (B1 in the example) with data validation (set to for example =Sheet1!$N$2:$O$2) would be helpful.
Please pardon the spelling errors ;), also please swap parameter separator , to ; as needed. Functions Translator to convert it is not working now.


=LET(
    comment_1, "Used for custom sort order",
    klasserna, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT("LD,LC,LB,LA,MsvB,MsvA,SvårB,SvårA", ",")),
    num_rows, 100,
    data, Sheet1!$A$4:INDEX(Sheet1!$AP:$AP, num_rows),
    competition_name, $B$1,
    header_main, TRIM(Sheet1!$A$3:$M$3),
    header_competition, TRIM(Sheet1!$A$2:$AP$2),
    col_num_competion, XMATCH(competition_name, header_competition),
    col_nums_for_detail, XMATCH({"Hästnr.", "Hästens namn", "Ägera"}, header_main),
    competion_col, CHOOSECOLS(data, col_num_competion),
    filter_by, LEN(TRIM(CHOOSECOLS(data, col_num_competion))) > 0,
    sort_by_col, FILTER(
        MAP(
            competion_col,
            LAMBDA(a,
                LET(
                    split, TEXTSPLIT(a, ":"),
                    TEXT(IFERROR(XMATCH(INDEX(split, , 1), klasserna), 100), "000")  
                    & "-" & TEXT(--INDEX(split, , 2), "000")
                )
            )
        ),
        filter_by
    ),
    report_header, HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(header_main, col_nums_for_detail), CHOOSECOLS(header_competition, col_num_competion)),
    report_data, SORTBY(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(data, col_nums_for_detail, col_num_competion), filter_by, "None"), sort_by_col),
    VSTACK(report_header, report_data)
)



Start a new line of text inside a cell in Excel - Microsoft Support
